# Full text search algorithm c#

Tags: c#, sql, search, full-text-search

I have a list of object: list(brought from an sql database). Every student has an attribute called Article=article written by this student like:

```
  public class Student

  {

     public string Article
     {
        get;
        set;
      }
  }
```

From my asp.net page users need to search words ,phrase in students articles. The students matching the user search are shown in a datalist.

For example when the user type: `phrase="Object Oriented Programming"`, I need to find all students whom the article contains one the possible combinations of words of the typed phrase:Like "programming", "Object Oriented", "Oriented", ....

I have tested with full text index in the database, and it's very slow and I have a problem in embedding wildcard % in a dynamic sql string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The .NET port of Lucene  might be your best bet... http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at [LIFTI](http://github.com/mikegoatly/lifti)